# Display JComboBox selected item in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcombobox

I'm using `JFrame` GUI to drag and drop elements and I'm currently working on combo box. Below is the GUI.

[image]

When the Button "Press" is clicked, it will add numbers into the combo box as below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        String str_rep = Integer.toString(i);
        jComboBox1.addItem(str_rep);
    }
    jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(null);
 }
```

Once the numbers are added into the combo box, I **set the selected item to null** because I **didn't want** the combo box **to display the first element** once the button is pressed.

However, the issue I'm facing currently is that I coded the `jLabel2` to display what is being selected based on the combo box, but once the "Press" button is pressed, the label automatically display the first number which is 0, even if I set the combo box selected item to `null`.

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jLabel2.setText(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

[image]

Is there any way I can **prevent the label from displaying the first number** once the **button is pressed**? It should **remain as label** until I select a number from the combo box, then it will be updated to that number.

Comment: according to your code there is no way that jLabel displaying the first number once the button is pressed.

Comment: Please post your full code ([mcve]). Then we can run it and see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In `ComboBoxAndLabel` class, I tried to recreate your problem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboBoxAndLabel {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel("jLabel2");

    JComboBox<String> jComboBox1 = new JComboBox<>();
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jLabel2.setText(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
    });

    JButton button = new JButton("Press");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
          String str_rep = Integer.toString(i);
          jComboBox1.addItem(str_rep);
        }
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(null);
      }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jComboBox1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jLabel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setBounds(400, 300, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

When I run above program, I see below error in the console (I guess you also get this error).

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at ComboBoxAndLabel$1.actionPerformed(ComboBoxAndLabel.java:21)
  at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
  at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
  at ComboBoxAndLabel$2.actionPerformed(ComboBoxAndLabel.java:35)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
```

The problem here is, `jComboBox1.addItem()` method sets the selected item when the combo box is empty (See the source code of `DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement()`). That's why you have had to call `jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(null)`.

But if you use `jComboBox1.setModel()` instead of adding items one by one, then selected item will NOT be set automatically. So, you don't need to call `jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(null)` as well. You can change `jButton1ActionPerformed` like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
      String str_rep = Integer.toString(i);
      comboBoxModel.addElement(str_rep);
    }
    jComboBox1.setModel(comboBoxModel);
}
```

**Full executable solution:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboBoxAndLabelSolution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel("jLabel2");

    JComboBox<String> jComboBox1 = new JComboBox<>();
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jLabel2.setText(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
    });

    JButton button = new JButton("Press");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
          String str_rep = Integer.toString(i);
          comboBoxModel.addElement(str_rep);
        }
        jComboBox1.setModel(comboBoxModel);
      }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jComboBox1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jLabel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setBounds(400, 300, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```